# how to make sound stop playing on button push

Tags: python, tkinter

i am very new to coding and have a school project in which you push buttons on the screen and sound plays but i need to make it so that when a new button is pressed all sound from other buttons stops playing.
here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from replit import audio

window1 = tk.Tk()

window1.title("Sounds")
window1.geometry("490x220")

frame1 = tk.Frame(window1)
frame1.pack(pady=(0, 0))

frame2 = tk.Frame(window1)
frame2.pack(pady=(0, 20))


def song1():
  audio.play_file("soviet anthem.mp3")

def play_sound2():
  audio.play_file("star spangled banner.mp3")

def play_sound3():
  audio.play_file("god save the king.mp3")

def playsound4():
  audio.play_file("german song.mp3")

myimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="dog.gif")
myimage1 = myimage.subsample(2, 2)
image_label = tk.Button(frame1,image=myimage1, height=100,command=song1)
image_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 20))

myimage2 = tk.PhotoImage(file="american.gif")
myimage3 = myimage2.subsample(12, 12)
image_label2 = tk.Button(frame1, image=myimage3,height=100,command=play_sound2,)
image_label2.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(20, 0))

myimage4 = tk.PhotoImage(file="british bulldog (1).gif")
image_label3 = tk.Button(frame2, image=myimage4, height=100, command=play_sound3)
image_label3.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(0, 20))

myimage6 = tk.PhotoImage(file="german shepard (1).gif")
myimage7 = myimage6.subsample(1, 1)
image_label4 = tk.Button(frame2,image=myimage7, height=100, command=playsound4)
image_label4.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=(20, 0))

tk.mainloop()
```

i have tried researching this but i cannot find how to.

Comment: Try something like  `current_song=audio.play_file("soviet anthem.mp3")` and then use `current_song.set_paused(True)` to stop it?